# no internet at all

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Hi
after installing the version 14.04 lts I have no internet access (wifi and wire) even though spending loads of time browsing and following all the steps in order to sort this out.

My wireless is a chip ID: BCM 4312; PCI-ID: 14e4:4315; kernel drive: b43-pci-bridge
Network controler:broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

So far I have used b43driver (firmware b43 installer) and broadcom sta wireless driver. I have received error messages

I have no internet access at all in this machine, even Ethernet. I have to use another machine, and a usb memory drive to pass on all the drivers. My machine is a dell inspiron 1720

Im novice in this OS so I would welcome an detailed reply if possible.

Thanks

Comment: *what* error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I see this complaint frequently especially regarding 14.04.  Please click on your internet icon at the top of your screen and make sure networking has not been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that the firmware is there `sudo ls /lib/firmware/b43 | grep ucode`
If you get output from that command in terminal then you can do the following

```
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe ssb
sudo modprobe b43
```

If wireless works after that you can uninstall the broadcom STA driver that you installed and reboot as installing the Broadcom STA will blacklist 5 or 6 other modules including one that might be needed for ethernet